# "Spring Data JPA - Exception: 'No Property Found for Type' with Inheritance Between Repository Interfaces"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two repository interfaces.

One is more generic:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface JpaGenericRepository<T> {

    List<T> find(Query<T> query);

    long count(Query<T> query);

    List<T> findAllCache();

}
```

The other one extends it, passing the entity class (Profile in this case):

```
public interface ProfileJpaRepository extends JpaGenericRepository<Profile> {

    List<Profile> findAll();

    List<Profile> findByProfileStringProperty(Set<String> property);

}
```

The implementation is as follows:

```
public class ProfileJpaRepositoryImpl extends AbstractJpaRepository<Profile, Long> implements ProfileJpaRepository, Serializable {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4013787249678288423L;

    @Override
    public Optional<Profile> findById(Long id) { /* method implementation */ }


    @Override
    public List<Profile> findAll() { /* method implementation */ }


    @Override
    public List<Profile> find(Query<Profile> query) { /* method implementation */ }

    @Override
    public long count(Query<Profile> query) { /* method implementation */ }

    @Override
    public List<Profile> findByProfileStringProperty(Set<String> property) { /* method implementation */ }

    @Override
    public List<Profile> findAllCache() { /* method implementation */ }

    public JPAQuery<Perfil> createQuery(Query<Profile> query, boolean sortAndPaging) { /* method implementation */ }
}
```

The error message states:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'count' found for type 'Profile'
```

It seems that the implementation of the `count` method inside `ProfileJpaRepositoryImpl` is not being recognized. Can you help me figure out why?

`Profile` class :

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "PERFIL")
@Relation(collectionRelation = "profiles")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "seqProfile",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
        parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "SEQ_PROFILE"),
                @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
        }
)
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Profile implements Serializable, GenericEntity<Profile> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2386088697024413736L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "seqProfile")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 1, max = 200)
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Audited(targetAuditMode = NOT_AUDITED)
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "PROFILE_PERMISSION", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PROFILE_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PERMISSION_ID"))
    private List<Permission> permissions;

    public Profile() {
    }

    public Profile(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private AuditLog auditLog;

    @QueryProjection
    public Profile(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @QueryProjection
    public Profile(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @QueryProjection
    public Profile(Long id, String name, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || !Util.classOf(this).equals(Util.classOf(o))) return false;
        Profile profile = (Profile) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.getId(), profile.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

`Query` class :

```
public final class Query<T> implements Serializable {

    public static final long LIMIT = 10L;

    public static final long NO_LIMIT = -1;

    private final Filter<T> filter;
    private final Sorter<T> sorter;
    private final Long page;
    private final Long limit;

    // getters, setters and constructors
}
```

```
public abstract class AbstractJpaRepository<T, ID> {

@Serial
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7633557834565897303L;
protected final Class<T> entityClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
protected DecisorManager decisorManager;
protected Class<? extends T> daoType;
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
@Autowired
private BeanUtil beanUtil;

public AbstractJpaRepository() {
    daoType = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
            .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

public static List<Field> getAllFields(List<Field> fields, Class<?> type) {
    fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(type.getDeclaredFields()));

    if (type.getSuperclass() != null) {
        fields = getAllFields(fields, type.getSuperclass());
    }

    return fields;
}

/**
 * Returns whether the entity's ID is automatically generated.
 *
 * @return
 */
private boolean isGeneratedId() {
    return Arrays.stream(entityClass.getDeclaredFields()).anyMatch(field -> field.isAnnotationPresent(GeneratedValue.class));
}

/**
 * Find an entity by its ID.
 *
 * @param id
 * @return
 */
public Optional<T> findById(ID id) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(entityManager.find(entityClass, id));
}


public T findById(ID key, String... columns) {
    try {
        if (columns == null || columns.length == 0) {
            return entityManager.find(daoType, key);
        } else {
            // PERFORM THE QUERY
            return (T) returnCriteria(columns).add(Restrictions.eq("id", key)).uniqueResult();
        }
    } catch (NoResultException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Insert a new entity.
 *
 * @param entity
 */
public void create(T entity) {
    Optional<ID> id = getIdentifier(entity);
    if (isGeneratedId() && id.isPresent()) {
        // TODO - ADJUST MESSAGE ON RESOURCE REFACTORING
        throw new BusinessException("New message");
    } else if (!isGeneratedId() && !id.isPresent()) {
        // TODO - ADJUST MESSAGE ON RESOURCE REFACTORING
        throw new BusinessException("New message");
    } else {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        entityManager.flush();
        if (decisorManager.checkDecisor(entity))
            applicationContext.publishEvent(new CamundaLogEvent(EnumEventoDecisor.AOINCLUIR, entity));
    }
}

public void createWithoutCamunda(T entity) {
    Optional<ID> id = getIdentifier(entity);
    if (isGeneratedId() && id.isPresent()) {
        // TODO - ADJUST MESSAGE ON RESOURCE REFACTORING
        throw new BusinessException("New message");
    } else if (!isGeneratedId() && !id.isPresent()) {
        // TODO - ADJUST MESSAGE ON RESOURCE REFACTORING
        throw new BusinessException("New message");
    } else {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        entityManager.flush();
    }
}

/**
 * Update an entity.
 *
 * @param entity
 */
public void update(T entity) {
    this.findById(this.getIdentifier(entity).orElseThrow(BusinessException::new)).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
    entityManager.merge(entity);
    entityManager.flush();
    if (decisorManager.checkDecisor(entity))
        applicationContext.publishEvent(new CamundaLogEvent(EnumEventoDecisor.AOALTERAR, entity));
}

public void updateBaixaTarefa(T entity) {
    this.findById(this.getIdentifier(entity).orElseThrow(BusinessException::new)).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
    entityManager.merge(entity);
    entityManager.flush();
    if (decisorManager.checkDecisor(entity))
        applicationContext.publishEvent(new CamundaLogEvent(EnumEventoDecisor.AOBAIXAR, entity));
}

public void updateWithoutCamunda(T entity) {
    this.findById(this.getIdentifier(entity).orElseThrow(BusinessException::new)).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
    entityManager.merge(entity);
    entityManager.flush();
}

/**
 * Remove an entity.
 *
 * @param entity
 */
public void remove(T entity) {
    removeById(getIdentifier(entity).orElseThrow(BusinessException::new));
}

/**
 * Remove an entity by its ID.
 *
 * @param id
 */
public void removeById(ID id) {
    entityManager.remove(Optional.ofNullable(entityManager.find(entityClass, id)).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new));
    entityManager.flush();
}

/**
 * Clear the cache of an entity in the decisor manager.
 *
 * @param entityCadastro
 */
public void clearCacheDecisor(String entityCadastro) {
    decisorManager.clearCacheDecisor(entityCadastro);
}

/**
 * Get the ID of the entity.
 *
 * @param entity
 * @return
 */
protected Optional<ID> getIdentifier(T entity) {
    return Optional.ofNullable((ID) entityManager
            .getEntityManagerFactory()
            .getPersistenceUnitUtil()
            .getIdentifier(entity));
}

/**
 * Apply sorting to the query based on the {@link JPAQuery} and {@link Sorter}.
 *
 * @param jpaQuery {@link JPAQuery} used to perform the query, must already have the query itself prepared.
 * @param sorter   {@link Sorter} containing information about the property to be sorted.
 * @return {@link JPAQuery} with the sorting prepared.
 */
protected JPAQuery<T> applySorter(JPAQuery<T> jpaQuery, Sorter<T> sorter) {
    final PathBuilder<T> path = new PathBuilder<>(this.entityClass, this.entityClass.getSimpleName().substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + this.entityClass.getSimpleName().substring(1));

    if (Objects.nonNull(sorter) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(sorter.getProperty())) {
        if (sorter.isDesc()) {
            jpaQuery.orderBy(path.getString(sorter.getProperty()).desc());
        } else {
            jpaQuery.orderBy(path.getString(sorter.getProperty()).asc());
        }
    } else {
        jpaQuery.orderBy(path.getString("id").asc());
    }

    return jpaQuery;
}

protected JPAQuery<T> applySorter(JPAQuery<T> jpaQuery, Sorter sorter, PathBuilder<T> path) {

    if (Objects.nonNull(sorter) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(sorter.getProperty())) {
        if (sorter.isDesc()) {
            jpaQuery.orderBy(path.getString(sorter.getProperty()).desc());
        } else {
            jpaQuery.orderBy(path.getString(sorter.getProperty()).asc());
        }
    } else {
        jpaQuery.orderBy(path.getString("id").asc());
    }

    return jpaQuery;
}

/**
 * Apply pagination to the query based on the {@link JPAQuery}.
 *
 * @param jpaQuery {@link JPAQuery} used to perform the query, must already have the query itself prepared.
 * @param page     {@link Long} representing the page to be queried.
 * @param limit    {@link Long} representing the number of records to be displayed per page.
 * @return {@link JPAQuery} with the pagination prepared.
 */
protected JPAQuery<T> applyPagination(JPAQuery<T> jpaQuery, Long page, Long limit) {
    if (Optional.ofNullable(page).orElse(0L) > 0L) {
        jpaQuery.offset(((page - 1L) * limit));
    }

    if (!limit.equals(Query.NO_LIMIT)) {
        jpaQuery.limit(limit);
    }

    return jpaQuery;
}

public String getSelectNew(Class<?> tipoDestino, Class<? extends Entidade> tipoOrigem) {
    String prefix = tipoOrigem.getSimpleName().substring(0, 1).toLowerCase();
    return getSelectNewPrefix(tipoDestino, tipoOrigem, prefix);
}

public String getSelectNewPrefix(Class<?> tipoDestino, Class<? extends Entidade> tipoOrigem, String prefix) {
    String table = tipoOrigem.getSimpleName();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Select distinct new ").append(tipoDestino.getName()).append("(");

    Map<Integer, String> campos = new HashMap();
    boolean foundAtLeastOneFieldInConstructor = false;
    for (Field campo : getAllFields(new LinkedList<Field>(), tipoDestino)) {
        ViewInterface viewInterface = campo.getAnnotation(ViewInterface.class);
        if (viewInterface == null) continue;
        campos.put(viewInterface.ordem(), viewInterface.campo());
        foundAtLeastOneFieldInConstructor = true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < campos.size(); i++) {
        sb.append(campos.get(i)).append(", ");
    }

    sb.append(") from ").append(table).append(" ").append(prefix);

    if (!foundAtLeastOneFieldInConstructor) {
        sb = new StringBuilder("Select distinct ")
                .append(prefix)
                .append(" from ")
                .append(table)
                .append(" ")
                .append(prefix);
    }

    return sb.toString().replace(", )", ")");
}

public List<?> listByQueryGeneric(String queryString, List<Object> parametros, int maxResults) {
    int index = 1;
    while (queryString.contains("?") && parametros.size() > 0) {
        queryString = queryString.replaceFirst("\\?", ":param" + index++);
    }

    javax.persistence.Query query;
    if (maxResults > 0) {
        query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString).setMaxResults(maxResults);
    } else {
        query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
    }

    index = 1;
    for (Object parametro : parametros) {
        query.setParameter(("param" + index++), parametro);
    }

    return query.getResultList();
}

private Criteria returnCriteria(String... colunas) {
    // Create criteria based on the entity example
    Criteria criteria = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).createCriteria(daoType);

    // Check if attributes were passed to avoid querying all object information
    if (colunas != null && colunas.length > 0) {

        ProjectionList listaColunas = Projections.projectionList();

        for (String coluna : colunas) {
            listaColunas.add(Projections.property(coluna.trim()), coluna.trim());
        }

        criteria.setProjection(listaColunas).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(daoType));
    }

    // Perform the query
    return criteria;
}
```

Comment: You can annotate the JpaGenericRepository  interface with '@NoRepositoryBean' and delete the '@Repository' for : ProfileJpaRepository  and ProfileJpaRepositoryImp .

Comment: @skillup, thanks for your comment :). Unfortunately, your suggestion was one of my initial unsuccessful attempts.

Comment: Spring Data search count() method and you have your own method count(Query<Profile> query) , you can change the signature of this method only for test, like this long count(); thanks.

Comment: Now he's complaining about ```findByProfileStringProperty``` method.

```No property 'findByProfileStringProperty' found for type 'Profile' ```

Comment: can you put the code of AbstractJpaRepository.java